# How do I found out which process creates a tilde "~" directory in my home folder

Tags: filesystem, process, logs

Some process keeps creating a directory named ~ in my home folder. How do I find out which process is doing this? I couldn't find anything useful in the syslog.

I can use `ls -l` to find the time it was created, but what I really want is to find out how/why it's created and stop that process.

Sadly the user/group is just me and so there's no hints there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the system to create that file you can do

```
while true; do lsof /home/$USER/~; done;
```

Not pretty, hackish but it works without installing any tools.

You can also use an [audit tool](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) for this called [auditctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man8/auditctl.8.html):

```
auditctl -w /home/$USER/~
```

would then do the same. You can install this with

```
sudo apt install -y auditd audispd-plugins
```

---

Do check your environment variables. The cause, for this issue, turned out to be a wrongly set  `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`

Comment: That audit tool is exactly what I need. I've set a rule and later today when the directory comes back, I'll finally know what's going on there.

Comment: you found it? @patrick

Comment: Yes and no. It's me, somehow. So I'm pretty sure it's one of my aliases or bash functions. I've accepted your answer because it gave me all the information I can expect it to give me.

Comment: I now have the both the application doing this, chromium, and the reason. I had set in my bashrc file XDG_CONFIG_HOME='~/.config' which was wrong. I changed it to XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config, uninstalled chrome, reinstalled it and everything's now fine. 

So this just confirms that @Rizwind's answer was the correct one because before I could figure out how I messed up, I first needed to know that it was in fact me and not a software bug of some kind. 

If you find this post because you've got the same problem check your environment variables.

Comment: good one! glad you found out what it was Added it to the answer in case the comments get deleted :)